# Access denied for the new user role created in admin side in magento 2.1.7

Tags: admin-panel

I have created new user with some roles assigned, then when trying to login with the new user credentials then giving me the below error

[image: Admin Role Issue]

Please if anyone has ever faced this kind of issue let me know the solutions thanks in advance